# pandas.Series.str.cat() not working on last element of the pandas Series

Tags: pandas, string, series, cat

I am trying to concatenate each string element of a pandas Series object with `'.NS'`. My sample code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
asSeries = pd.Series(['HCLTECH', 'ADANIPORTS', 'HDFC', 'TECHM', 'ONGC', 'DIVISLAB', 'TCS'])
```

To concatenate each element with `.NS`, I am using the following code:

```
asTextWithNS = asSeries.str.cat(sep='.NS ')
print(asTextWithNS)
```

The result is as follows:

```
HCLTECH.NS ADANIPORTS.NS HDFC.NS TECHM.NS ONGC.NS DIVISLAB.NS TCS
```

As you can see, the last element is not concatenated with `.NS`, and I have checked with many other longer lists, and, invariably, I am not getting the concatenation on the last element. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes this is logical - the separator is not appended to the last element because it *separates* elements (and there's no element after to the last to be separated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour - you're concating strings using a separator, no reason for the separator to be thrown at the end. Just add it manually.

```
asTextWithNS = asSeries.str.cat(sep='.NS ')
print(asTextWithNS + '.NS')
```

Outputs

```
HCLTECH.NS ADANIPORTS.NS HDFC.NS TECHM.NS ONGC.NS DIVISLAB.NS TCS.NS
```

Comment: I guessed it that I will do it as a last resort. Looks like that is the only way out as of now. Thanks a lot!!!